# Importing Python modules in large projects and "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror, sys.path

I have faced a rather famous issue while importing my python modules inside the project.

This code is written to replicate the existing situation:

- `multiply_func.py`:

```
def multiplier(num_1, num_2):
    return num_1 * num_2
```

- `power_func.py`:

```
from math_tools import multiplier

def pow(num_1, num_2):
    result = num_1
    for _ in range(num_2 - 1):
        result = multiplier(num_1, result)
    return result
```

The project structure:

```
project/
│   main.py    
│
└─── tools/
    │   __init__.py
    │   power_func.py
    │
    └─── math_tools/
        │   __init__.py
        │   multiply_func.py
```

I've added these lines to `__init__` files to make the importing easier:

- `__init__.py` (math_tools):

```
from .multiply_func import multiplier
```

- `__init__.py` (tools):

```
from .power_func import pow
from .math_tools.multiply_func import multiplier
```

Here is my main file.

- `main.py`:

```
from tools import pow

print(pow(2, 3))
```

Whenever I run it, there is this error:

```
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math_tools'
```

I tried manipulating the `sys.path`, but I had no luck eliminating this puzzling issue. I'd appreciate your kind help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You messed it up in the "power_func.py" file.
You have to use . before math_tools to refer to the current directory module.

Update "power_func.py" as bellow, it works perfectly.

```
from .math_tools import multiplier
```